# How to conditionally set classes for table rows | SvelteKit

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following code in a SvelteKit project:

```html
<table class="AddressTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#each gooddata as item, i}
       <tr class="bg-rose-200">      
          <td>{i + 1}</td>
          <td class="nine">{#if item.contact} {item.contact} {/if}</td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the table row class is now bg-rose-200.

I want the table row to have different class base on item.country.

For example if `item.country == 'uk` the row will have class bg-green-200

If `item.country == 'us` the row will have class `bg-black-200`

If `item.country == 'canada` the row will have class `bg-yellow-200`

If `item.country == 'singapore` the row will have class bg-purple-200

How to do that ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, more clarity please. However are you looking for `Class Directive` https://www.okupter.com/blog/conditional-classes-in-svelte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Svelte not SvelteKit so apologies if this isn't applicable to your issue.

I added the following function to basically just check against a string and return a string in this case your classes. Not the most efficient approach but it might work for you.

```
  const handleContryClass = (country) => {
    if (country === 'uk') return 'bg-green-200'
    if (country === 'us') return 'bg-black-200'
    if (country === 'canada') return 'bg-yellow-200'
    if (country === 'singapore') return 'bg-purple-200'

    //add other classes

    return 'bg-rose-200' // Default class
  }
```

And then in your HTML call the function like this.

```
<table class="AddressTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#each gooddata as item, i}
       <tr class={handleContryClass(item.country)}>      
          <td>{i + 1}</td>
          <td class="nine">{#if item.contact} {item.contact} {/if}</td>
        </tr>
    {/each}
  </tbody>
</table>
```